# Get other fields in Kendo MultiSelect Change event

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-multiselect

I'd like to update a `label` on change event of the Kendo Multi Select. But the `value()` just gives the Id. Do you have any idea about accessing other fields of the selected value?

This is the JavaScript handler:

```
function change(e) {
    if (e.sender.value()[0])
        $("#Label").text(e.sender.value()[0]);
    else
        $("#Label").text('');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `var value = this.dataItems();` instead, it will give you all information you need about the current selected value, and do note because it's multi select it's value may more than 1.

```
function onChange(e) {
    var value = this.dataItems();
    console.log(value[0].text);
    if (value[0]){
        $("#Label").text(value[0].text);
    }else{
        $("#Label").text('');
    }
}
```

> [DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/OSowO)